How to reconnect Pycharm/Intellij to git after a connection problem?
The IDE is stubbornly displaying:

Error updating changes: Cannot Run Git: Cannot identify version of Git executable: no response


I have closed/reopened the Git Tooling a few times but to no effect. Is there any way to jog the memory of git subsystem without an [expensive] restart of the IDE?

There's a "refresh" button in the Commit window. Does that work for you?

No that button did not work. I did have to restart the IDE. I do have an itch that there is another way to reconnect to git but can't recall how it were done.

This was happening on the latest version of my IDE as well. I can't say for sure when it started happening, but it's pretty new.
To fix go to "Version Control -> Git", confirm your path is pointing to your local git installation, if it isn't update it. If it already is, click the "Test" button right next to the installation path.

If successful go and click the "refresh" button on your "Git" or "Commit" views, this should fix it.



Thanks for confirming that this is a new tiny bug and how you found a workaround.
